# Plotting Multiple Proportions With Standard Error

Tags: r, data-visualization, proportion

The Data:
The observed probability (proportions) of three mutually exclusive events for five species.

What is the best way to plot these data in R along with their standard errors? I'd like to avoid a "beside" bar plot with error bars (3 bars for each species). I was hoping to use a stacked bar plot, but I'm unsure how to incorporate standard error!

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to imagine a stacked barplot with SE bars (at least for me!). Why not simply use a [dotplot](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/dot.html)?